# scanf for string and number in C

Tags: c

I've been trying to use scanf() for reading string and integer. It works fine, but I am unable to check if the input is given correctly.

```
char command[6];
int cmd_num;

scanf("%5s %d", command, &cmd_num);
```

It works fine for reading the right input, I am able to **check if the string is right by strcmp**. I tried to check the number by the function **isdigit()**, but it cannot check correctly, I guess because of whitespaces, but I am not sure exactly how it works.

I tried to google this, I played around with [^\n] but still it doesn't work. Could anyone enlighten me how scanf exactly works please?

I think solution would be if I exactly could tell scanf what to read ->string(space)integer. Is it possible to acquire this with regular expressions or any other way?

**What I need basically is to scanf read the line recognize the string and then to check if there is a number after it too.**

Another question is, I need to read the input for as long as the user is giving it, I tried to use getchar for while loop, to repeat as long as the char is not '\n' but this closes the loop right in the beginning, but if I give it EOF condition it never ends even with multiple newlines. I guess it could be limited by the scanf too, but I am not sure exactly how, threads on this forum couldn't give me the answer for it.

This will not procced:

```
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n')
{
 //code
}
```

This will proceed no matter of newlines:

```
while ( (c = getchar() ) != EOF )
{
 //code
}
```

Comment: " I tried to check the number by the function isdigit(), but it cannot check correctly": isdigit(), as iharob  correctly said, is for single characters. What exactly do you want to check? Whether there is a number at all? scanf() will tell you: If the second "word" is not a number, scanf will return with a return value of 1.

Comment: One thing to consider is that the stricter the input is defined, the easier it is to process it. May the number be optional? Then make it mandatory. Much easier for a start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't check if a number is a number, and `isdigit()` is used to check if an ascii value is a number between `0` and `9`.

To check that `scanf()` succeeded and the input is correct, thus the value of `cmd_num` is correct and is an integer read from the input, you have to check the return value of `scanf()`.

It returns, the number of matched format specifiers. You have two of them so

```
if (scanf("%5s%d", command, &cmd_num) == 2) // this means it's correct
//                          ^ your code is missing the address of operator
```

Comment: @L.Kratky That is not very specific. It would help to see what input you made and what was unexpected.